# Parameterising a surface of revolution

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Consider the surface of revolution defined by the curve $z=2+\sin x$ between $z=0, z=2\pi$ rotated around the $z-$axis. Parametrise this surface.

The problem I have is that in general whilst I know how to parameterise surfaces, this seems a little complicated. We could possibly have $p(t)=(2+\sin t, t, t)$ where $t$ ranges between $0,2\pi$ but I don't think that works

Comment: @Paul how should I go about solving this problem? I really have no clue

Comment: Do you mean $z = 2+sin(x)$ rotated about the z axis?

Comment: @Paul I do indeed, I'll correct this now

Comment: For each $x = r$ as you rotate you get a circle in the $x,y$ plane. Can you parametrize that circle? Now simply add the $z$ coordinate and you have $(x,y,z)$ dependent on two parameters.